# Ruby & OOP: FizzBuzz Game

Tags: object-oriented, ruby, fizzbuzz

I would like a more elegant solution for this problem, I think the `FizzBuzzArrayBuilder` class is not used properly. Also can those `if` statements be removed somehow?

Any suggestion on how to improve this by still using OOP is welcome.

**Problem:**

Given the array `[1, 2, 3, 4, ... 100]`, print all the elements as follows:

- if the element can be divided by 3 print: `Fizz`
- if the element can be divided by 5 print: `Buzz`
- if the element can be divided by both 3 and 5 print: `FizzBuzz`
- else print the number

**Output:**
`1, 2, Fizz, 4, Buzz, Fizz, 7, 8, Fizz, Buzz, 11, Fizz, 13, 14, FizzBuzz ...`

**Solution:**

```
class Fizz
  def output
    puts 'Fizz'
  end
end

class Buzz
  def output
    puts 'Buzz'
  end
end

class FizzBuzz
  def output
    puts 'FizzBuzz'
  end
end

class Element
  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end

  def output
    puts @value
  end
end

class FizzBuzzArrayBuilder
  def initialize(array)
    @array = array
  end

  def build
    result = []
    @array.each do |e|
      if e % 15 == 0
        result << FizzBuzz.new
      elsif e % 3 == 0
        result << Fizz.new
      elsif e % 5 == 0
        result << Buzz.new
      else
        result << Element.new(e)
      end
    end
    result
  end
end

class Counter
  def initialize(array)
    @fizz_buzz_array = FizzBuzzArrayBuilder.new(array).build
  end

  def output_array
    @fizz_buzz_array.map(&:output)
  end
end

array = (1..100).to_a
Counter.new(array).output_array
```

Comment: Is there a reason you went for this specific approach?

Comment: I want an object oriented approach, more than that not really.

Comment: I agree with Zack. This is a trivial problem and can be solved in one line of Ruby. The OO structure seems forced and a little too Java flavored. There's just no way to reason about the OO unless the problem gets a bit more sophisticated. Learning OO includes knowing when *not* to use it :)

Comment: I don't say this to be mean, but it should be said because it's important that you know it: this code is comedically over-engineered.  You really need to ask yourself why you would ever want something like this when you can write something like [this](https://gist.github.com/Kerrick/2483510#gistcomment-915913)

Answer (score 2):

#### Wrong Objects

You've made objects, but you haven't really made the right ones.  Your `Fizz`, `Buzz`, `FizzBuzz`, and `Element` classes are really just wrappers for a string, which is already a class.

Object oriented programming is not always the best solution for a problem.  FizzBuzz itself is frankly very trivial and almost any object based approach is a needlessly complicated solution.  With that said, perhaps we can redefine the problem to make it a better fit for an object oriented solution.

#### New problem definition

Consider this modified problem: As input you will receive a list.  Each row (a rule) will have one or more numbers (divisors) and a text substitution.  After parsing the list, for every number 1..100 you will either print the number or a substitution for the number.  For each rule, if a number is divisible by all of the divisors, you will use the substitution.  In the event of a tie, use the substitution from the rule with the most divisors.  If there is still a ties use the substitution for the rule with the smallest individual divisor.  For example, given "3 6 apple" and "2 9 banana" and "18 candle", they all tie for an input of 18, but "2 9 banana" has the smallest divisor, 2.

```
Example Input:
3 fizz
5 buzz
3 5 fizzbuzz
3 6 apple
2 9 banana
18 candle
2 3 4 dog
```

#### New Classes

Now there is opportunity for new classes, perhaps `Parser` that reads the rules/substitutions, `Rule` which contains a list of divisors, the substitution, and perhaps it supports the comparison operation <=> so that the rules can automatically resolve ties.  There could also be an `Engine` class for iterating through 1..100 and applying the rules.  There are a couple of different ways you could define the classes or even the problem here. In general though, OO solutions to trivial problems aren't a good fit.